# Ubuntu: Mpsyt do not work from cron

Tags: ubuntu, cron, dbus

When I type:

```
mpsyt .La isla bonita, 1
```

It works.

When I copy it to cron. It doesn't.
I requested to send output to file: `>mpsyt.log 2>mpsyt.error.log`

Log:

```
mpris interface couldn't be initialized. Is dbus properly configured?
```

^[]2;mpsyt^G

Error log is empty.

It seems that cron do not start mpris/dbus api/interface. How to make it work?

I want to use that with Google Assistant. When cron script detects an order to play a song, it should use mpsyt to find and play it.

K.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28463/run-a-dbus-program-in-crontab-how-to-know-about-the-session-id/28496#28496

Answer (score 0):

Guy from github sent me an answer.

1. Mpsyt has to be in newest vesrion (that feature has been probably added because of my issue).
2. mpsyt set mpris false, /La isla bonita, 1
3. Command from 2 will play La isla bonita from cron.

K.